# amCharts map function. JS, Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, amcharts

It is necessary that the user, when clicking on the button with the country, then a window pops up on the map above the selected country

```
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

// Set themes
root.setThemes([
    am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

var chart = root.container.children.push(
    am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
        wheelY: "none",
        projection: am5map.geoEquirectangular()
    })
);

// Create polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(
    am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
        geoJSON: am5geodata_worldLow,
        exclude: ["AQ"]
    })
);

polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
    interactive: true,
    fill: am5.color(0xDDDBEC)
});

// button function to display the selected country
function placeMarker(country) {
    // var countryName = country.split(',')[0];

    var countryContent = `here is the html code of the window`

    var modal = modal = am5.Modal.new(root, {
        content: countryContent
    });

    modal.open();
}
```

and you need to close the previous pop-up window when you click on the button again, maybe without a library tell me how to implement it.

**screenshot of map**
[image: screenshot of map]